# Are there any reporting library in Javascript/Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, report

I want to generate some reports in a MEAN.js Application, that said, i manage the data in Angular, what i want to know is if there's a library to generate a PDF Report, for example, when using PHP there's *dompdf*, *fpdf*, etc...

Basically what i need to generate is something like this from Angular:

[image: report]

Are there any tool to generate the reports from Angular, or should i generate them from Node.js? if so what are the tools available for node.js? 
I only know about [jsreport](http://jsreport.net/) for node.js

Comment: I need a tool to generate a **pdf** @dandavis

Comment: 1. https://medium.com/@darilldrems/angularjs-export-html-table-to-pdf-excel-or-doc-formats-bb741d06dfec#.nt7wc81w0                                                   2. https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf

Comment: The first link post doesn't show anything at all, second link seems to be just a viewer, not a pdf generator @javababy

Answer (score 1):

Server-side rendering with Node is definitely the way to go, the client side libraries never really worked well (I last checked about a year ago). I'd suggest using PhantomJS as it provides PDF rendering capabilities out of the box.

PhantomJS will use Webkit engine to generate the PDF for you. The actual rendering process is dead simple:

```
page.render('/tmp/file.pdf', function() {
  // file is now written to disk
});
```

Of course you have to insert something on the page you're generating first. Check out the following post which describes one guy's implementation, the code quoted above comes from there: http://www.feedhenry.com/server-side-pdf-generation-node-js/

Comment: So from the client how will i access the pdf?

Comment: Basically  `res.download('/file.pdf', 'file:///tmp/file.pdf');`. Your file will be available at localhost:3000/file.pdf (or whatever your express URL is).

You can also turn it into a stream, depending on your needs. This should be a good start though.
There is a fuller description in [the link](http://www.feedhenry.com/server-side-pdf-generation-node-js/) provided in my original answer.